# A Riddle - Mountains and Valleys

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Mountains and Valleys, over and under
>   Be careful you do not tear it asunder
>
> Boats and planes, birds and flowers
>   Create almost anything with this power
>
> What could it be? You'll have to guess
>   I hope you don't fold under the stress.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answer:

> Origami

Reasoning:

> Mountains and valleys are different types of creases. 
>  When you crease too hard, it becomes easy to rip. 
>  You can create many shapes with folding paper. 
>  "Don't fold under the stress" implies folding.

Comment: Ah! Just beat me to it.

Comment: well done getting the answer, and explaining each line too! The second stanza was meant to contrast how many different kinds of 'paper folding' fall under the umbrella of origami, from paper boats and paper airplanes to more traditional designs like flowers and cranes. 'fold under the stress' was maybe a bit of a giveaway, but too good of a phrase not to use!